# How to make custom cart link share (opencart)

Tags: plugins, opencart, cart

Hello how to make Opencart Cart , shareable ? I mean someone choose products and he can share the cart with someone ?

Something like --> http://nikem-bg.net/cart/57887p1rf.html (i am sorry for the language) I pick some item and i can share and send with anyone ?